# Testing value identity in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm a relatively green Rcpp user, and I'm unsure how to test if two values are identical.

For example, the following function is meant to test if a value is contained within a list, but returns incorrect results for simple test cases

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;    

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector is_member (SEXP val, List coll) {    

    int coll_len = coll.size();    

    if (coll_len == 0) {
        return LogicalVector::create();
    } else {    

        Function identical("identical");    

        for (int ith = 0; ith < coll_len; ++ith) {    

            SEXP elem = coll[ith];    

            if (identical(val, elem)) {
                return true;
            }
        }    

        return false;
    }
}

is_member(1L, list(1L))
# FALSE
is_member(NaN, list(NaN, NaN))
# False
```

Why is this, and how can you test for identity with the same corner cases and durability of the base function 'identical'? I couldn't find any Rcpp sugar for this purpose, but if I can't find a direct solution I suspect unordered sets or the unique function might be used to test for identity.

If my C++ is non-idiomatic / dangerous I would also appreciate feedback, and if I've been to vague please leave a comment below and I'll amend my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh, looks like you stumbled on a little bug -- we aren't converting `bool` to `LogicalVector` in the expected way.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
LogicalVector return_true() {
  return true;
}

/*** R
return_true()
*/
```

gives

```
> return_true()
[1] FALSE
```

So maybe just return `LogicalVector::create(true)` for now?

One other big problem in your code: `identical` returns a `SEXP`, not a `bool`! You want to get the result as a `bool` explicitly:

```
Shield<SEXP> result(identical(val, elem));
if (LOGICAL(result)[0]) { ... }
```

Although assigning the result directly to `bool` should work, it seems like maybe it doesn't. There are still traps like this when calling back to R.

That said, other comments on your code:

1. Generally, calling back to R is slow*, so don't do it unless you have to,
2. Don't use raw `SEXP`s unless you know what you're doing. Here you are getting lucky since children of `List`s are implicitly protected, but in general this is unsafe.
3. Just call your iterator index `i`, that is the most common format (feels weird seeing `ith`).

It turns out there is a C API for `identical` available as well. In `RInternals.h`, we have

```
/* R_compute_identical:  C version of identical() function
   The third arg to R_compute_identical() consists of bitmapped flags for non-default options:
   currently all default to TRUE, so the flag is set for FALSE values:
   1 = !NUM_EQ
   2 = !SINGLE_NA
   4 = !ATTR_AS_SET
   8 = !IGNORE_BYTECODE
*/
Rboolean R_compute_identical(SEXP, SEXP, int);
```

so you may want to just use that instead.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply; that bug would have taken me years to hunt down! I'm using the C api now, the code is more performant now.